# Linear interpolation between two numbers with steps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I've a little trouble finding out how to linearly interpolate between two numbers with a defined number of intermediate steps.

Let's say I want to interpolate between 4 and 22 with 8 intermediate steps like so : [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUOJz.png)

It's easy to figure out that it's x+2 here. But what if the starting value was 5 and the final value 532 with 12 intermediate steps? (In my special case I would need starting and ending value with 16 steps in between)

Comment: How did you get `x+2`? Can you solve your second example by hand?

Comment: It would give something ugly @Code-Apprentice but : 
45.53846154
86.07692308
126.6153846
167.1538462
207.6923077
248.2307692
288.7692308
329.3076923
369.8461538
410.3846154
450.9230769
491.4615385

Comment: @Pouissante What do you want intstead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two fence posts and you put k fence posts between them, you create k + 1 spaces. For instance:

```
|           |
post1       post2


      adding one posts creates two spaces
|     |     |
post1       post2
```

If you want those k + 1 spaces to be equal you can divide the total distance by k + 1 to get the distance between adjacent posts.

```
d = 22 - 4 = 18
k = 8
e = d / (k + 1) = 18 / 9 = 2
```

In your other case example, the answer is

```
d = 532 - 5 = 527
k = 12
e = d / (k + 1) = 527 / 13 ~ 40.5
```

Comment: Mhh, thinking back I have trouble figuring out why it has 9 steps since I have 8 numbers to "discover". If I take your posts example I can only figure out that I have placed 7 posts between start and end, therefor k+1 would be 8?

Comment: @Pouissante Your "steps" are actually the posts in my example. If you're thinking of "steps" as the space between posts, your new way of thinking is neglecting the step from the last intermediate post to the rightmost post. If there is a first step, a last step, and N intermediate steps, to get from the first to the last (starting on the first) means you need to take (N + 2) - 1 steps; +2 because N intermediate steps + 1 initial step + 1 final step; -1 because you are assumed to already be on the initial step so don't need to step to touch it.

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate to produce two separate answers, but I feel this methodology is sufficiently unique from the other one. There's a useful function which may be exactly what you need which is appropriately called [`Mathf.Lerp()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html).

```cs
var start = 5;
var end = 532;
var steps = 13;
for (int i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
    // The type conversion is necessary because both i and steps are integers
    var value = Mathf.Lerp(start, end, i / (float)steps);
    Debug.Log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For actually doing the linear interpolation, use [`Mathf.MoveTowards()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.MoveTowards.html).

For figuring out your maximum delta (i.e. the amount you want it to move each step), take the difference, and then divide it by the number of desired steps.

```cs
var start = 4;
var end = 22;
var distance = end - start;
var steps = 9; // Your example technically has 9 steps, not 8
var delta = distance / steps;
```

Note that this conveniently assumes your `distance` is a clean multiple of `steps`. If you don't know this is the case and it's important that you never exceed that number of steps, you may want to explicitly check for it. Here's a crude example for an integer. Floating point methods may be more complicated:

```cs
if (distance % delta > 0) { delta += 1; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. If the step is not an integer, I will cast it, I don't need floating points.

Comment: I actually intend to post a second answer, because it's a very different methodology that may be better suited to your needs.

Comment: Mhh, thinking back I have trouble figuring out why it has 9 steps since I have 8 numbers to "discover".

Comment: It depends on if you count your starting value as a step, or if you consider steps to be the act of moving from one value to another.